# How to pass user uid from login page to a different page in a web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm logging in users via firebase-auth and need to pass their user uid to the redirected page. How can the user-uid be passed?

I've tried using the docs on firebase auth but cant quite solve it

```
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

    const email = loginForm['email'].value;
    const password = loginForm['password'].value;

    console.log(email, password);
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(cred => {


        if(email ==='admin@mombasa.com' && password ==='adminMomb') {
            window.location = './admin-map.php';
        }
            else if(email ==='admin@nairobi.com' && password ==='adminNai') {
                window.location = './admin-map.php';
            }
           else if(email ==='admin@eldoret.com' && password ==='adminEld') {
                window.location = './admin-map.php';
            }


           else firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

                    window.user = user;
                    console.log('logged in ', user);
                    window.location = './dailyreports.php';
                    console.log('logged in ', user);

            });

        }).catch(
        function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
            console.log(errorMessage, errorCode);
        }
    )
    ;


});
```

On navigation to the next page, I expected to see the user-uid output in the console but it returns blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the UID, it's better to pick up the state in the next page with a so-called authentication state listener.

As shown in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

There will be no delay in picking up the user account this way on the new page, as the Firebase SDK will be able to restore the state from the information it stored in local storage.

Comment: Okay, so I put this code at the beginning of the next page's js file?

Comment: Moreover, I want to get the user uid because I need to update a document in firestore which has a field corresponding to the user uid

Comment: 1) It doesn't really matter where in the file you put it, as long as it runs early on. 2) You can get the UID in the call back, inside the `if (user)` block, for example with `console.log(user.uid)`.